# Could dwarves do without wood?

Tags: technology, medieval, engineering, fantasy-races, underground

Wood has, historically, been used, and still is, to make a great variety of things. Indeed, this material has many qualities, the most relevant being:

- Commonplace: in most places in your typical fantasy setting, you never have to go very far to find trees.
- Easy to harvest and work with: chopping a tree down only requires simple tools and relatively little time and labor. It's also rather easy to cut, shape and assemble.
- Strong and light: it's neither brittle nor malleable, and a relatively thin plank or pole is able to hold its own weight and then some.
- Comes in long, slender pieces: this make it especially great for building free-standing structures.

Now, consider dwarves. A material with such qualities would be very useful to them. But dwarves live underground, and trees don't grow underground.

So what materials, that are readily available underground, could dwarves use in place of wood? There are obvious candidates, but they are either too heavy and hard to work with (stone), to fragile for most uses (clay), or require lots of infrastructure and labor to make (metal)...

So would a dwarven kingdom need to regularly send lumberjacks out on the surface, or be reliant on wood imports? Or are there alternatives?

For reference, here are some things I think dwarves would need wood for:

- Scaffolding to temporarily support construction or provide access to elevated areas.
- Crude fortifications (palisades) that can be erected quickly and with minimal dwarfpower.
- Crates to store goods and materials, and carts to transport them.
- Doors and (movable) furniture such as tables, chairs, benches, etc.

Comment: Woods other major use is as fuel, which is arguably more important.

Comment: @John dwarves, arguably, have easy access to coal.

Comment: @John crude oil is also available underground.  Though 'wood as fuel' was my first though as well.  Though now that I think about it, I wonder about other plant life, especially cotton, for clothing ... cave-sheep?

Comment: You should search for underground questions a lot of this has already been covered.   Dwarves might also work.

Comment: Cooking with coal requires wood coal needs another fire before it will light. cooking with crude oil is a great way to poison your dwarves.

Comment: Pratchett had a interesting way to deal with this. Dwarves do come above ground but only at night, and the dwarves that do are considered strange or desperate like miners for humans.

Comment: the romans used clay for storage more than wood, wood is not great for storage, clay ceramics on the other hand is water tight and can be made air tight. https://img1.cgtrader.com/items/734520/1fe27d98f8/roman-amphora-pack-3d-model-low-poly-obj-3ds-fbx-blend-mtl-pdf.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are always alternatives, and there are certainly places where not much wood grows so I'll use those (compounded with a cave environment) as an example.

#### Adding: Fuel (cannot make a forge work without fuel and need it to cook)

- Use [Dry Animal Dung as Fuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_dung_fuel) which is a common practice in various parts of the world (and presumably would ***include Dwarf dung if not enough animals are available***). Now normal animal dung would only work for cooking or as a "starter log" for the forges but as this is fantasy - it is conceivable that a [monster that eats rock](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/d-d-monsters-that-eat-rock.414826/) or magic might exist whose dung would provide a higher energy output.
- Coal: I didn't put this at first because I thought it was too obvious but Dwarves will have access to deep coal mines which would help them in finding [Anthracite coal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthracite) for their forges. (if they can make charcoal even better, I know it can be made from items such as sugar, petroleum, and coal itself, but someone with more biochem knowledge would have to add more beyond that).

#### Scaffolding to temporarily support construction or provide access to elevated areas.

- Once again: [dried animal dung](https://www.globalcitizen.org/en/content/who-uses-sht-to-build-a-house/) was used as a fairly sturdy building material since at least the Iron Age in Britain and is still used today in some areas (and modern wattle and daub construction can use chicken wire and plaster/dry wall so using metal wire & dung would avoid needing wood).
- For access to elevated areas - make dung or mud bricks and stack them to make stairs. Straw replacement for brick making could use moss or ferns or animal hair (which could also be braided into rope and used to make rope ladders).

#### Crude fortifications (palisades) that can be erected quickly and with minimal dwarf power.

- This one I'm going to take directly from the military: make [Hesco](https://www.hesco.com/products/mil-units/) barriers using *metal* wire, cloth (which could be made using some **[Sphagnum moss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moss#Commercial)** or **[certain ferns like Horsetail](https://www.fs.fed.us/database/feis/plants/fern/equarv/all.html)** which the dwarves cultivate from cave [entrances and twilight zones](http://www.caveslime.org/kids/cavejourney/caveJourneyWhatPlants.html)), and then filled with rocks/gravel, mud, or sand as available.

  - rocks would be best as they would get stuck in wire making enemies have to take time cutting the wire itself(....and hopefully end up with it falling on them).
  - I can personally attest to these being quick to put up but a pain to get around/take down.

#### Crates to store goods and materials, and carts to transport them.

- Use metal? Think A-frame carts, dollies, wheelbarrels (one of the first wheeled carts actually), a little red wagon - all of these are mostly made of metal. And the first wheels were actually made of stone (granted they were potters wheels but the point stands)
- Also, since talking fantasy, animal bones have been used to make containers (bone china cups) and shells to make boxes (turtle shells and snuff boxes) so if you have a suitable monster you could use its bones, shell, or carapace.

#### Doors and (movable) furniture such as tables, chairs, benches, etc

- Mudbricks (or Dung ones) could be molded and shaped around metal frames to build these but I would not use that for much more than stools or small tables.

  - However, making clay or mudbrick sliding doors might be an option.
- Another option for the furniture would be to make more cloth (moss/ferns again) or leather (assuming animals) and then wrapping and drying that around a metal frame - think cloth patio furniture.
- A third option could be to use fibers to weave furniture.

  - My Grandmother used to weave dollhouse furniture for my sisters from grapevines so a solid, strong vine could be used.
  - Currently hemp or animal rope can be used to make items like hammocks so I see no reason this couldn't be taken further to make rope furniture.

    - This makes me think of men making a "chair" using their treated and braided beard hair which would really be "dad's chair" :)
- An animal/monster's bones - there is one artist who [made a table out of marbel and animal bones](https://www.ft.com/content/369fb48a-9ea9-11e7-8b50-0b9f565a23e1) so its certainly possible.

  - Could just use the Marble itself too (I've moved marble slabs they are certainly not light-weight but are movable)
- Glass - this would depend on if they could generate enough heat to melt sand (1700°C or 3090°F - which is a few hundred degrees higher than needed to melt iron). Then its just glass tabletop with wire or bone legs.

<sup>*If your interested, I have used this [page on minerals and material available through mining](http://tao-dnd.blogspot.com/2010/09/mining-metals-minerals.html) from **The Tao of D&D** for a few campaigns I've built*</sup>

Comment: Your Dwarves can also create some kind of root farms.
Consider that, if they live underground below a forest then they can create some kind of root farms for those type of trees that have deep thick roots, and harvest them methodically.

Then use these roots to create wire-frames, and cover these frames with animal dung. This can give them solid and light weight frames.
Use these for Scaffoldings, furniture, crates and so on.

Comment: It's a good answer, but consider adding coal as fuel, it seems quite obvious as you can dig it out of the rocks, which seems like a very dwarven thing to do

Comment: Animal dung will work for cooking it will not work in a forge, coal would work in a forge but it does not work as well as charcoal.

Comment: Dwarves would have the same problems obtaining dried animal dung as they would with obtaining wood.  (Or food, FTM.)  Animals don't produce food unless they eat, and they eat plants (or other animals that ultimately eat plants).  Plants require sunlight, so must come from the surface.  (Likewise fungi: their food is ultimately derived from plants.)

Comment: @jamesqf presumably the dwarves themselves poop so there is at least that (and there are always monsters which subside on non-biological material - due to "fantasy races" tag). Also most of the plant (and other organic) material in deep caves is washed down from the twilight and [entrances](https://www.nps.gov/grba/learn/nature/cave-life.htm). And the "un-natural" presence of the dwarves can help algae to grow (lights, different food sources) and animals to eat the algae and animals to eat the animals and ...

Comment: @bytepusher I actually thought that was too obvious so didn't add it but yes, coal miner would probably be a respected job in dwarven society.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal I would (having grown up in a rural area) not mess with plant roots if you want them to continue growing (this is indeed a big problem with clear cutting - just leave the stumps of trees an you will have new ones in 25 years or so but damage the roots.....). But if you want to research this and add an answer I think it would be awesome (and add a great way to make charcoal with the sawdust)

Comment: grapevine is wood, its just not trees. Also fibers come from above ground, so no rope either.

Comment: @John - I'm not suggesting grape vines themselves just referencing that vines can be made into rope if vines are near the entrance (as opposed to harvesting full trees) could suggest poison ivy instead which I did use in a campaign due to dwarf resistances (poor itchy, itchy attackers) or a less "woody" vine. Also - rope can be [made from hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope#History) or [animal skin](http://www.the-ropewalk.co.uk/ks2th2.pdf) (i.e. leather or [rawhide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rawhide_(material))) so rope should not be a problem

Comment: All vines require sunlight, and getting animal skins is just as hard as getting wood. without a magical ecosystem they will not have any of those resources, they likely won't even have food.

Comment: @John requires [*light energy* of a certain wavelength](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/are-household-led-bulbs-suitable-as-supplemental-light-for-plants) not necessarily sunlight (though it is certainly optimal). We also know life exists in deep caves (I'm not putting up any more research on this see links in comments/answer) and plant life exists up to the twilight zone in deep caves so it would likely be accessible to the dwarves.

Comment: Second, we know humans hanging electric lights and giving off our own waste have increased plant growth in caves so it is conceivable that dwarves moving into a mountain might change conditions (such as light and food availability due to their heat/waste) enough to eventually have enough plant life to support themselves - in a ***fantasy setting***. There is no hard science tag - I only like to have might happen, could happen, or even just is believable enough by using supporting actual science and there is enough here.

Comment: The twilight zone is a very small part of a cave, if your entire civilizations caves are mostly twilight zone (enough to supply food and fibers you need far more than the equivalent amount of farm land) your not living in caves your living in a shady canyon. The only light dwarves have to grow plants is sunlight, unless magic in which case that's your answer magic. in fact if they are growing food and fiber using magic why not trees?

Comment: @JGreenwell: None of that (other than magic, of course) would work to support a dwavish community.  There just isn't enough energy in debris or chemosynthesis.  A single Gollum might survive on fish that eat things washed down in underground rivers, but even he had to supplement his fish diet with the occasional young orc :-)

Comment: @jamesqf not in our reality (world/whatever) but like I said - there is a fantasy race tag and I only need to get to a certain level of believable the "grain of truth". After that it is story-based (do you make rock eating monsters who support the foodchain/ecosystem or dwarves actually eat rocks or ...). So if the OP or anyone else wants a reality answer - make a hard science based question on building a self-supporting community in deep caves. This is what I have seen work for small groups - so can be expanded in fantasy without being ***too*** disjointed from reality.

Comment: note: not a sardonic suggestion as the research was interesting (deep cave ecosystem) when I read it for this answer so I'd at least upvote a question like the one proposed in the above comment (might be one already too - haven't looked).

Comment: @JGreenwell: But what's that "grain of truth" consist of?  To me, it's much more "truthy" to have your dwarves or whatever embedded in a realistic society, even if that larger society is only hinted at.  As for instance Tolkien did, with the Shire hobbits obtaining dwarf-made things like clocks & toys, presumably in trade for foodstuffs.  And in ancient days, the dwarves of Moria having extensive trade with the above-ground folk of Hollin.

Comment: @jamesqf where did I say they would not have to trade? Every society has to trade (even high fantasy magical empires like Melnibone had to trade) or conquer in the case of Mordor. But that's not the question that was asked - so I simply answered the 4 criteria given (and one about fuel because cooking with coal/oil is bad for human's health and may be the same with dwarves though that is not true in all fantasy worlds). This gives the OP an option when building a world based on research I have included in answer and comments on limiting the amount of wood dwarves need by using alternatives

Answer (score 5):

The dwarves as a hardly and skilled race capable of carving stone as humans can carve wood. Dwarves live underground and this means that a lot of the reasons for wood would actually be pointless.

Dwarves do not need scaffolding. They carve their homes into stone. If they carve up, they first carve a staircase or ladder up. Otherwise, whats the point? they wouldn't be able to reach it anyway. For the majority of their constructions, dwarves are going to be carving downwards. Why? because its much easier to start at the top of a solid mountain of stone and go down, than build ladders all the way up. Digging up is risky. You have falling debris which could destroy your scaffolding or injure others, you require lots of scaffolding to get to everywhere. Much easier to plan and design the building, build a staircase up to the top and debris shaft along the side and dig down from the top.

Fortifications are also better made out of stone. Dwarves are skills workmen and can quickly assemble giant walls from simply rock scraps. If you haven't seen the hobbit, it has a good example of the dwarves handiwork. They have no need for something as soft and hard to obtain as wood. Plus, its good for their waste rock. Got to do something with all that debris.

Crates and carts can also be carved out of stone. Big stone containers with big stone lids. No reason to go find something that will rot away over time. This also includes furniture like doors, beds, tables and chairs. The dwarves don't need some weak flimsy wood. They want firm and hard stone.

You have to remember that traditional dwarves lived in mountains. This implies that they had the ability to work stone with their own hands. Otherwise, it would of been much easier for them to develop above ground like humans did.

As an alternative... from dwarf fortress... they can user tower caps, a subterrain tree that grows in a mushroom shape? Or maybe its a mushroom that grows like a tree?

Answer (score 3):

**Less-than-'traditional' metals**

There are metals that don't need to be heated in order to be shaped, and are found in their "native" form (not in an ore mixed with other minerals).  How abundant are they? not very, unfortunately, at least in the real world, but then again, more abundant than the dwarven race.

Gold, Cadmium, and Indium might make good candidates.  With skill, it should be possible to work them in to shapes thick enough to be strong, and thin enough to not be absurdly heavy.  Though some applications would still make them significantly heavier than wood, it should still be light enough to be useful and effective, especially if these dwarves follow the trope of higher strength to size ratios.

Comment: Upvoted just for the thought of haphazardly-erected golden scaffolding.

Answer (score 2):

Even more important than wood is food, which must ultimately come from the surface.  Therefore, your underground-living dwarves have three options:

1) Low-status dwarves go above ground to do farming, woodcutting, &c, just as low-caste humans do things like garbage collection.

2) Dwarves keep human* slaves/serfs to do the above ground work.

3) Dwarves trade what they mine, and their skilled metal & stone work, for what they need from above.

Of course the three aren't mutually exclusive.  A dwarf community might use a mix of them.

*Or other races.